# Как отправить данные массива из PHP при работе с API на сервер?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть у меня вот такая API документация: https://toproi.biz/help/api.php#ext
Но я очень далека от PHP
Подтолкните в нужную сторону, или дайте почитать внятное что-то.
Сейчас задача простая:

```
<?php
$order = [
"name" => "Тест тест",
"phone" => "+79111111111",
"webmaster_id" => 65,
"id" => 123456,
"offer" => "200",
"ip" => "1.1.1.1"
];
send($order);
function send($order) {
Что прописать здесь?
}
```

Отправить данные из order на сервер
Всё это нужно выполнить, когда пользователь жмет "Заказать товар".

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php

Comment: Для начала вам лучше читать про то, как искать в Интернете что вам нужно, а так же как формулировать запросы к поисковым движкам для получения ответов на базовые вопросы по языку программирования. А уже после этого приступать к чему-то более сложному. Без способности самообучения с использованием ресурсов Интернета вам будет стократ сложнее находить, отсеивать и использовать нужную информацию.

Comment: В самом верху документации есть готовая функция, которую можете взять себе